# Flutter: Dart Convert properly null safety my class

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

How to change my class for null safety compliant?

My error for converting my project to null safety.

- error • The parameter '`bloc`' can't have a value of 'null' because of
  its type, but the implicit default value is 'null' at
  `lib/blocs/bloc_provider.dart:10:32` •
  (`missing_default_value_for_parameter`)
- error • The parameter 'child'    can't have a value of 'null' because
  of its type, but the implicit    default value is 'null' at
  `lib/blocs/bloc_provider.dart:10:53` •
  (`missing_default_value_for_parameter`)
- error • A value of type '`BlocProvider<T>`?' can't be assigned to a
  variable of type '`BlocProvider<T>`' at
  `lib/blocs/bloc_provider.dart:14:9` • (`invalid_assignment`)   error •
  The property '`length`' can't be unconditionally accessed because the
  receiver can be '`null`' at
  `lib/ui/login/components/sponsors_stagiaire_tab.dart:147:28` •
  (`unchecked_use_of_nullable_value`)

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

import 'blocs.dart';

class BlocProvider<T extends Bloc> extends StatefulWidget {
  final T bloc;

  final Widget child;

  BlocProvider({@required this.bloc, @required this.child});

  static T of<T extends Bloc>(BuildContext context) {
    final BlocProvider<T> _provider =
        context.findAncestorWidgetOfExactType<BlocProvider<T>>();
    return _provider.bloc;
  }

  State createState() => _BlocProviderState();
}

class _BlocProviderState extends State<BlocProvider> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.child;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.bloc.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'bloc' and 'child' parameters have a null value so you need to put '?' to indicate that that value can be null. 
The error "The property 'length' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null' at.." warns you that you need to ensure there is a value there, to ensure this you need to use '!'.
Below is an example of what I meant.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

import 'blocs.dart';

class BlocProvider<T extends Bloc> extends StatefulWidget {
  final T? bloc;

  final Widget? child;

  BlocProvider({this.bloc, this.child});

  static T of<T extends Bloc>(BuildContext context) {
    final BlocProvider<T> _provider =
        context.findAncestorWidgetOfExactType<BlocProvider<T>>();
    return _provider.bloc;
  }

  State createState() => _BlocProviderState();
}

class _BlocProviderState extends State<BlocProvider> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.child!;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.bloc!.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: error • A value of type 'BlocProvider<T>?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'BlocProvider<T>' at lib/blocs/bloc_provider.dart:14:9 • (invalid_assignment)
  
error • A value of type 'T?' can't be returned from the method 'of' because it has a return type of 'T' at lib/blocs/bloc_provider.dart:15:12 • (return_of_invalid_type)

i try return new error

Comment: just change BlocProvider<T> for BlocProvider<T>? and T for T? in these lines doesn't work?.  final BlocProvider<T?>? _provider =
            context.findAncestorWidgetOfExactType<BlocProvider<T?>?>(); . Now I'm just making assumptions because I don't know your entire code, but basically where you change the types allowing null (ie putting '?') you should refactor to the rest.